Line thickness in circuitikz looks bad when rasterized
Is there any way to make the line thickness uniform?
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    every node/.style={font=\sffamily},
      smallckt/.style={/tikz/circuitikz/bipoles/length=0.8cm},
]

\draw 
  (0.5,1.5) coordinate (tailpos) to [short, *-] ++(0,0.1) 
    to [smallckt, american current source, invert, n=Ibiasn] ++(0,1)
    to [short, -o] ++(0,0.1) node[above]{$V_{DD}$}
  (0,0) to [Tpigfete, n=Qnpos] ++(0,1) |- (tailpos)
  (1,0) to [Tpigfete, mirror, n=Qnneg] ++(0,1) |- (tailpos)
;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}



Everything looks bad when rasterized (espeically at 72 dpi).

@JohnKormylo, if that were an answer, I'll accept it ;-). Avoid rasterizing --- especially when lines are meant to be subpixel and with antialiasing --- is the reason why I use TikZ in general.

This is mainly a rendering (and probably antialiasing) problem. The only solution is to rasterize at high resolution and hope for the best. Some PDF viewers are better, and some are worse.
The following results are with your code untouched:
Okular, at 125% resolution (ouch!):

Again, Okular at 100% (better for the lines, but quite awful IMHO --- fonts are really messy):

Same Okular, at 400% (quite perfect)

Yes, antialiasing is hard...
(Notice that the last version is not perfect. Horizontal lines are nominally the same width, but you can see it's different in pixels: that depends on how the "ideal" line falls within pixel boundaries).

"The only solution is to rasterize at high resolution and hope for the best." -- why? if there are collinear line segments abutting each other, why wouldn't they show up as equivalent to one longer line segment?

@JasonS that is a good question. I suppose that it happens because each element is rendered independently; the antialiasing and line-preserving algorithms are probably quite sensitive to the exact positions of the lines, and composing that with the fact pgf uses native TeX arithmetic (low precision) make numerical errors build up... It would be very nice to see if a l3math-based pgf could do better.
